# Find if all nodes in BST are greater than a item

Tags: python

I have been working on trying to implement the function all_bigger below but I am not sure if there are flaws in my logic. To my understanding, BST's are organized having the smallest values on the left side so I would only need to check the left side of the BST. Is there a better way of writing this or is my code incorrect?

```
class BSTNode:
"""A node is a BST """
    def __init__(self: 'BSTNode', item, left, right):
        self.item, self.left, self.right = item, left, right

    def all_bigger(self, value):
        """
        >>> bst = BSTNode(5, BSTNode(4), BSTNode(6))
        >>> all_bigger(bst, 2)
        True
        """
        while self.left:
            if self.left > value:
                self.value = self.left:
            else:
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: What's t in ``` while t.left:```?

Comment: @DeepakSaini I have updated my code sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, with some minor bugs. Corrected code:

```
class BSTNode:
    """A node is a BST """
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item, self.left, self.right = item, left, right

    def all_bigger(self, value):
        """
        >>> bst = BSTNode(5, BSTNode(4), BSTNode(6))
        >>> all_bigger(bst, 2)
        True
        """
        root = self
        while(root!=None):
            if root.item > value:
                root = root.left
            else:
                return False
        return True

bst = BSTNode(5, BSTNode(4,BSTNode(1, None, None),None), BSTNode(6,None,None)) # Returns False
print(bst.all_bigger(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC your question is to see if all the nodes in the BST are bigger than a certain value.

A simple way to do is to find the node with the minimum value in the BST and compare it with the other value. The smallest node is going to be the left-most node.

A typical BST node looks like this

```
# A binary tree node
class Node:

    # Constructor to create a new node
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

And yes, you're right. The tree does not need to be searched fully, ie, the right subtrees can be skipped. This is how you find the node with the minimum value.

```
def minValue(node):
    current = node

    # loop down to find the lefmost leaf
    while(current.left is not None):
        current = current.left

    return current.data
```

This can be slightly tweaked to solve your problem

```
def all_bigger(node, val):
    current = node

    # loop down to find the lefmost leaf
    while(current.left is not None):
        current = current.left
        # Check if the current node value is smaller than val
        if current.data < val:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the node after every comparison. Kindly check the below code:

```
class BSTNode:
"""A node is a BST """
    def __init__(self: 'BSTNode', item, left, right):
        self.item, self.left, self.right = item, left, right

    def all_bigger(self, value):
        """
        >>> bst = BSTNode(5, BSTNode(4), BSTNode(6))
        >>> all_bigger(bst, 2)
        True
        """
        while self.item:
            if self.left > value:
                self.item = self.left:
            else:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

All values in a subtree are greater than X if and only if

- The value in the node is greater than X, and
- All values in its left subtree (if it exists) are greater than X

Assuming an empty tree is `None`:

```
def all_bigger(self, value):
    return self.value > value and self.left and self.left.all_bigger(value)
```